# display form fields in different tables

Tags: django, templates, field

In my template, I would like to display all the fields of my models with a for loop in different tables. Each table has a different number of fields. The only thing I know is the order of the fields.

My model:

```
class Act(models.Model):
    #table_1
    my_field=models.IntegerField(max_length=4, blank=False, null=False)
    bar=models.IntegerField(max_length=2, blank=False, null=False)
    ...

    #table_2
    test=models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    my_new_field=models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    blabla=models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    ...

    #table_3
    foo=models.IntegerField(max_length=2, blank=False, null=False)
    ...
```

My template:

```
<table id="table_1">
    <!-- display my_field and bar -->
    {% for field in form %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>

<table id="table_2">
    <!-- display test, my_new_field and blabla -->
    {% for field in form %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>

<table id="table_3">
    <!-- display foo -->
    {% for field in form %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: you can use something form.fieldname and form.fieldname mannually entering it each times

Comment: What if there are hundreds of fields?

Comment: are you gonna to use hundreds of fields in your template, There is other way you can use three different models connected by foreign key

Comment: First table: 10 fields, second:  15, third: 35. Is creating different models a good/acceptable solution?

Comment: if you knows the count you can use slice option too....,
{% for field in form|slice:":10" %} it 'll show up to ten fields even it's not the best solution for your question but a hint to get your work being done

Comment: `slice` seems to be a good solution  (not many things to change), thank you!

Comment: Welcome!  being Happy on helping You...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Anto Vinish, I have found an acceptable solution: use `slice`.

```
<table id="table_1">
    <!-- display my_field and bar -->
    {% for field in form|slice:":10" %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>

<table id="table_2">
    <!-- display test, my_new_field and blabla -->
    {% for field in form|slice:"10:25" %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>

<table id="table_3">
    <!-- display foo -->
    {% for field in form|slice:"25:" %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

You have to count right and update the numbers if you add fields in your model, but at least you have nothing else to change. No extra model, no extra code so no extra query.

Solved!